# Append a tag box inside an image after clicking on it

Tags: jquery, image, tagging

I'm trying to make a photo tag plugin for my website. I have long way to go. I know there are other actual plugins but I want to create my own here. The question is I was trying to make a box appear on a image after clicking it, it is not appearing, it is not appending on the image.

```
<head>
    <style>
    #imageHolder {
        position:relative;
        border:dashed 2px #7E7E7E;
        min-width:300px;
        min-height:300px;
        box-shadow:0 0 5px #000;
        cursor:pointer;
        float:left;
        }
        #tag
        {
          position:absolute;
          top:0;left:0;
          width:250px;
        }
        #box
        {
          border:solid 3px #000;
          width:100px;
          height:100px;
          float:left;
        }
    </style>

    <script style = "text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var mouseX = 0;
        var mouseY = 0;
        $("#imageHolder img").click(function(e){
          var imgBox = $(this).parent();
          mouseX = e.pageX - $(imgBox).offset().left;
          mouseY = e.pageY - $(imgBox).offset().top;
          $('#tag').remove();
          $(imgBox).append('<div id = "tag"><div id="box"></div></div>');
          $('#tag').css({top:mouseY,left:mouseX});
        });
    });
    </script> 
    </head>

<body>
<div id = "imageHolder">
<img src = "test.jpg"/>
</div>
</body>
```

What is the problem with this code?

Comment: any errors in console ??

Comment: check my answer and let me know what you think, any more features needed etc...

Comment: Even better http://jsfiddle.net/e4tr7/8/ click on the image where you would like the image to be added, you can drag the box and doubleclick the box to remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting and difficult yet very simple solution

### http://jsfiddle.net/e4tr7/5/

```
$("#imageHolder img").click(function (e) {
  var offset = $(this).offset();
  var position = {
    left: e.clientX - offset.left - 50,
    top: e.clientY - offset.top - 50
  }
  var append = $('<div class="tag"><div class="box"></div></div>').draggable({containment: "parent"}).css({"position":"absolute","top":position.top,"left":position.left});
  $(this).parent().append(append);

});
```

Comment: Thanks Yusaf. Thats my real name as well. Anyway, this example seems to work. I feel stupid because my example also worked, BUT, I didn't have jQuery in my library. So stupid. Regardless, your answer is better and glad I have it. I also updated it a little. Thanks.

Comment: ahhh you should see my updates.... http://jsfiddle.net/e4tr7/28/ .... please let me know what you think of them ;)

Comment: BTW after you hit save refresh the browser and see the magic ;)

Comment: I love it, but there is one problem! the problem is, if you click on the corner, the box is half way in, but we dont want the box in, we want to see the full box right after we click it.

Comment: nice, I just noticed about the storage, it works very well, I'll just have to query it to mySQL, it will work awesome!

Comment: yupp exactly what i was going to say, submit the json to your database and then recall it via a unique id simples :)

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems to work, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CRYXF/1/).

I moved the click function to the div, since the test.jpg image is not available. I also colored the divs to show it more clearly. Otherwise I left the rest of your code as is

```
$("#imageHolder").click(function(e){
  var imgBox = $(this);
```

Comment: Thanks so much but is there a way for the tagbox to not move outside the DIV? If you click on the corner, you will notice

Comment: @Cole You can add `overflow: hidden;`, to clip the tagbox to the outer imageHolder. See http://jsfiddle.net/CRYXF/2/, if this is what you mean.